# Error: "Current request is not a multipart request" react axios file + data submit

Tags: spring, reactjs, api, axios, postman

My final goal is upload file along with map using react axios. But file  upload is not working from react. I have tried with single file upload without map and get same error too. But by postman it works fine.

**Spring code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit-employee-profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editProfileEmployee(@RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam("user") Map<String, String> data) throws ParseException {
//      System.out.println(data.get("0"));
        return file.getOriginalFilename()+data.get("0");
    }
```

**react code**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
fullname: "",
avatar:null
};
this.inputFullnameRef = React.createRef();
}
```

handleSubmit:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const user = this.state;

data.append("user", [
      user.fullname]);
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/edit-employee-profile", null, {
        params: { avatar: this.state.avatar, user: user.fullname }})
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      });
}
```

handleUploadFile:

```
handleUploadFile = event => {
    this.setState({
      avatar: event.target.files[0]
    });
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
  };
```

handleInputChange:

```
handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
```

render:

```
render() { return(
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
 <input
 type="file"
 accept="image/*"
 name="avatar"
 onChange={this.handleUploadFile}
 />
 <Fullname
  inputRef={this.inputFullnameRef}
  value={fullname}
  name="fullname"
  defaultValue={this.state.fullname}
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
  required="required"
  />
 <Button className="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Confirm</Button>
</Form>)}
```

Component Fullname:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Fullname(props) {
  function handleChange(event) {
    if (props.onChange) props.onChange(event);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Full Name"
          required="required"
          value={props.value}
          name={props.name}
          ref={props.inputRef}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error is telling

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request